# Powerapps: Filter table with another table

Tags: excel, powerapps

I'm very new to powerapps and now struggling with creating first useful app.
I'm stuck at point where I'm trying to filter one list with items from another list.

For example:

Table1:

```
categoryName | categoryCode
---------------------------
category1    | 1
category2    | 2
category3    | 3
```

Table2:

```
itemName     | itemCategory
---------------------------
item1        | 1
item2        | 1
item3        | 3
```

What I'm trying to do is to show list of **category names** from `Table1`, but I want to show only those rows which contains categoryCode that is present in `Table2` in `itemCategory` column.

Both tables are loaded  from excel file located on my onedrive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use filter function to filter the categories that are present in table2. Use the filter function as below

```
Filter(Table1,categoryCode in Table2.itemCategory)
```

If you want to display this filtered list in a Gallery, use the above formula in `Items` property of the Gallery